# Get values in string - Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, python-2.7

I am new to Python so I have lots of doubts. For instance I have a string:

```
string = "xtpo, example1=x, example2, example3=thisValue"
```

For example, is it possible to get the values next to the equals in `example1` and `example3`? knowing only the keywords, not what comes after the `=` ?

Comment: try `x.split()[-1].split('=')` where x is your string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "xtpo, example1=x, example2, example3=thisValue"
>>> key = 'example1'
>>> re.search(r'{}=(\w+)'.format(key), strs).group(1)
'x'
>>> key = 'example3'
>>> re.search(r'{}=(\w+)'.format(key), strs).group(1)
'thisValue'
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @karthikr I am still not sure what OP is looking for, question is quite unclear.

Comment: @karthikr Actually I think it is, although the question could be worded better

Comment: @karthikr, I disagree. `x` and `thisValue` are the values next to the equals signs. So it's exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: Sorry for being specific.
However I think this what I am looking for. Tomorrow I´ll try in the "real" world" scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

Spacing things out for clarity

```
>>> Sstring = "xtpo, example1=x, example2, example3=thisValue"
>>> items = Sstring.split(',') # Get the comma separated items
>>> for i in items:
...     Pair = i.split('=')  # Try splitting on =
...     if len(Pair) > 1:    # Did split
...         print Pair       # or whatever you would like to do
... 
[' example1', 'x']
[' example3', 'thisValue']
>>>
```